# Multiplying a specific column in txt file with constant number

Tags: python, c++17

I have txt file with 7 column...I want to mutiply a 3rd column with a constant number keeping all other column same and then output the file containing all the columns. Anyone can help?

```
1 2 1
2 2 1
3 2 1
```

mutiplying column 3 with "14" the output should be like

```
1 2 14
2 2 14
3 2 14
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have a text file with `7` columns, your example only shows `3`.
So I have based my answer on your example:

The important part of code related to multiplication is this:

```
matrix[:,(target_col-1)] *= c_val
```

**Here is the full PYTHON code:**

```py
import numpy as np

# Constant value (used for multiplication)
c_val = 14

# Number of columns in the matrix 
n_col = 3

# Column to be multiplied (ie. Third column)
target_col = 3

# Import the text file containing the matrix
filename = 'data.txt'
matrix = np.loadtxt(filename, usecols=range(n_col))
    
# Multiply the target column (ie. 3rd column) by c_val (ie.14)
matrix[:,(target_col-1)] *= c_val

# Save the matrix to a new text file
with open('new_text_file.txt','wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, matrix, delimiter=' ', fmt='%d')
```

**OUTPUT:**

> new_text_file.txt

```
1 2 14
2 2 14
3 2 14
```

Comment: Your help much appericaited. It worked, but just want to know what changes to be made to the code if the number are not integers but floats/doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done as below:

```
MULTIPLIER = 14

input_file_name = "numbers_in.txt"
output_file_name = "numbers_out.txt"
with open(input_file_name, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open(output_file_name, 'w+') as f:
    for line in lines:
        new_line = ""
        for i, x in enumerate(line.strip().split(" ")):
            if (i+1)%3 == 0:
                new_line += str(int(x)*MULTIPLIER) + " "
            else:
                new_line += x + " "
        f.writelines(new_line + "\n")

# numbers_in.txt:
# 1 2 1 2 2 1 3 2 1
# 1 3 1 3 3 1 4 3 1
# 1 4 1 4 4 1 5 4 1
# numbers_out.txt:
# 1 2 14 2 2 14 3 2 14 
# 1 3 14 3 3 14 4 3 14 
# 1 4 14 4 4 14 5 4 14
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution for C++17.

If you are sure about the format of the input file, you could reduce the code to the one below:

- Just walk the input stream, multiply every 3rd number by a constant, and add a new line for every 10th number (you mentioned 7 numbers per line but then your example contained 9 numbers).
- Notice you would need to use file streams instead of string streams.

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <sstream>  // istringstream, ostringstream

void parse_iss(std::istringstream& iss, std::ostringstream& oss, int k) {
    for (int number_counter{ 0 }, number; iss >> number; ++number_counter) {
        oss << ((number_counter % 3 == 2) ? number*k : number);
        oss << ((number_counter % 9 == 8) ? "\n" : " ");
    }
}

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss{
        "1 2 1 2 2 1 3 2 1\n"
        "2 4 2 4 4 5 5 5 6\n"
    };
    std::ostringstream oss{};
    parse_iss(iss, oss, 14);
    fmt::print("{}", oss.str());
}

// Outputs:
//
//   1 2 14 2 2 14 3 2 14
//   2 4 28 4 4 70 5 5 84
```

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/TeqKrd4WE)